# Atypical merging in Google Sheets (only few common columns)

Tags: google-apps-script, merge, google-sheets

I know, that there are many threads about merging sheets, but I'm solving uncommon problem. I couldn't find the answer for this here. I have Google Sheets document, which is working as an IT inventory. I have many sheets in that document. There is for example sheet servers, cameras, switches etc... ([sheet - servers,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8FHM.png) [sheet - switches,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohZ7J.png) [sheet - cameras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQrhA.png)).

There are few common columns in each sheet like a locality, IP address, manufacturer, model etc. and a lot of specific columns for each kind of device. Servers have an operating system column, switches has a VLAN settings columns and so on... I need to use all these sheets and create one new overview sheet. There will be all common columns from all sheets and relevant records, so I could for example filter out all devices in one location and see their IP addresses, count devices in one location, sort all devices according to their IP address and so on. ([overview sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddeu7.png))

Was anyone solving this?

Answer (score 2):

So here it is. I wrote it:

```
function makeSummarySheet() {
  // spreadsheet ID
  var ID = '6Ca-aDgaHRsAALAh85vXjC79na4vgSOjs45Q6dOqxfQQ';
  // sheet names
  var sheetsArray = ["servers", "switches", "cameras"];
  // common columns - CASE SENSITIVE!
  var wantedColumns = [["name", "model", "locality", "IP address"]];
  // final summary array
  var overviewArray = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);

  var date = new Date();
  var dateTime = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " +  date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();

  if (sheetsArray.length >= 1) {
    for (var x = 0; x < sheetsArray.length; x++) {
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetsArray[x]);
      var sheetID = ss.getSheetByName(sheetsArray[x]).getSheetId();
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var columnNames = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();
      var sheetData = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, lastColumn).getValues();
      var cachedColumns = [wantedColumns[0],[]];    

      for(var i=0; i < lastColumn; i++) {
        for(var y=0; y < wantedColumns[0].length ; y++) {
          if (columnNames[0][i] == cachedColumns[0][y]) {
            cachedColumns[1][y] = i;
          }
        }
      }

      for(var i =0; i < sheetData.length-1; i++) {
        var tempArray = [];
        tempArray[0] = '=hyperlink("#gid='+sheetID+'&range='+sheet.getRange(i+2,cachedColumns[1][0]+1).getA1Notation()+'";"'+sheetData[i][cachedColumns[1][0]]+'")';
        for(var y=1; y < wantedColumns[0].length; y++) {
          tempArray[y] = sheetData[i][cachedColumns[1][y]];
        }
        overviewArray.push(tempArray);
      }
    }
  }

  var overviewSheet = ss.insertSheet("SUM " + dateTime, ss.getSheets().length+1);
  overviewSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, wantedColumns[0].length).setValues(wantedColumns).setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null).setFontWeight("bold");
  overviewSheet.getRange(2, 1, overviewArray.length, wantedColumns[0].length).setValues(overviewArray);    
  overviewSheet.getRange(1, 1, overviewSheet.getLastRow(), overviewSheet.getLastColumn()).createFilter();

}
```

edit: according to comment - "for each" replaced